# How to manage telegram group permissions with python telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I am making a telegram bot,

so how to manage group permissions with bot permissions like send message, send embeds etc...

I am trying for last 5 days please help me

use this as a reference [here](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/telegram/types/chat.html?highlight=permissions#aiogram.types.chat.Chat.set_permissions)

Answer (score 0):

I've found [this](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html?highlight=permission#telegram.Bot.set_chat_permissions) at the bot documentation